# Python: looking for a string within a string and then returning the strings around it

Tags: python, string

```
import time
with open('txt.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
pdf_content = data.split(" ")`
vocab = input('Vocab word to search for: ')

if vocab not in pdf_content:
    print('word not found....')
if vocab in pdf_content:
    for vocab in pdf_content:
        print((" ".join(pdf_content[1])))
time.sleep(200)
```

I want to basically search a body of text for a certain word and return a group of words around that 1 word.

ex. your paragraph is the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
and we wanted to search for brown, it would return quick brown fox since those are the surrounding words. I'm not sure how to do this but help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Formatting done

Comment: Find index of word and get your required o/p using index-1, index and index+1

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

text = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'

word = "brown"
for match in re.finditer(r"\w+\W+{}\W+\w+".format(word), text):
    print(match.group())
```

**Output**

```
quick brown fox
```

**Regex**

- `\w+` matches a word
- `\W+` followed by one or more characters that are not words
- followed by the chosen word, in this case `'brown'`

Answer (score 0):

**Or a one-liner**:

```
print(' '.join(s.split()[s.split().index(s2)-1:s.split().index(s2)+2]))
```

#### Demo:

```
s = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
s2 = "brown"
print(' '.join(s.split()[s.split().index(s2)-1:s.split().index(s2)+2]))
```

**Explanation:**

- join the strings of the index-1 to index+1 (+2 in this case)
- index meaning the index of `s2` in the split list from `s`

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the words and use indices:

```
pdf_content = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
word = "brown"

words = pdf_content.split()
pos = words.index(word)
found = word
if pos > 0:
    found = words[pos - 1] + " " + found
if pos < len(words) - 1:
    found = found + " " + words[pos + 1]

print(found)
```